# Trig identity problem using inverse functions

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking to solve the following exercise.

Show that $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})=\sec^{-1}(e^x)$

essentially I must simplify the left side of the equation but I'm not sure where to start. Any tips?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.  Please avoid [no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27923/290189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e^x =\sec\alpha$

So,$$\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}\right)= \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{(e^x)^2 - 1}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sec^2\alpha - 1}\right) = \tan^{-1}(\tan\alpha) = \alpha$$

From our first consideration, $\alpha =\sec^{-1}(e^x)$

Thus, $$\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}\right) = \sec^{-1}(e^x)$$

Comment: thank you. I'm a little unfamiliar working with inverse trig functions. Setting $e^x=\sec(\alpha)$ was the key idea I was missing.

Comment: Your welcome!!!

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove that:

$$\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})-\text{arcsec}(e^x)=0$$

If $f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})-\text{arcsec}(e^x)$, then:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}-\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}} $$

Do some calculus and you get:

$$f'(x)=0$$

This means that the function is constant in particular if you try $x=0$ you get $f(0)=0$ , this means that $f(x)=0$

:)

Comment: thanks, it's really useful to see differentiation being used in different contexts. It would have never occured to me to solve the problem this way even though Im fairly comfortable with differentiation problems. I guess as my understanding deepens I will begin to see these types of solutions